# Macro to raise compiler error for string literal C++

Tags: c++, macros

I know of the (evil?) C++ macro that raises a compiler error on all but string literal (found it in SO some time ago but cannot find it again):

```
#define IS_STRING_LITERAL(X) "" X ""
```

Is there a macro that can do the 'opposite', ie raise a compiler error on a string literal, but not on other inputs?

Edit: see comment, this is for debug macros on microcontroller. String literals should live in flash, I want to be notified at compiler time if I call the wrong macro. 'Others' should be int, float, char, char [] and other 'basic' type.

Comment: Why do you want one?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I want to write debug macros on Arduino. The macro called on string literals will use print on the F macro to not fill SRAM (only 2kB SRAM, and a hell to debug if goes empty; by contrat, much more Flash is available). If I call the wrong macro, without F, on a string literal, I want to be notified at compiler time.

Comment: PS: I can maybe think of a macro calling a template function undefined just on ``const char *``, but this sounds a bit convoluted.

Comment: What are valid parameters for that other macro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends what those 'other inputs' are. If they can be anything, then the answer is probably 'impossible'.

You could do something like this:

```
#define foo(x) (std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same_v<const char *, decltype(+(x))>>(), (x))
```

This line checks if `x` is `const char *` (or decays to one) and raises a error if it's true. (It's not what you asked for: it's impossible to pass a plain `const char []` into it.)

```
std::cout << foo(123); // Works.
std::cout << foo("123"); // error: no type named 'type' in 'struct std::enable_if<false, void>'
```

Comment: Weird, my Visual Studio doesn't show any error. The plus sign in decltype, what does it do? It forces it to do something?

Comment: @Zebrafish The `+` forces array-to-pointer decay. I mean I expected it to. :|

Comment: @HolyBlackCat why would you not just use `#define foo(x) decltype(x) var;` or `#define foo(x) void* var=(decltype(x)) x;` this detects an error of `missing initializer` because array litterals should always be initialized once declared.

Comment: @Abra001 I think OP wants the macro to return it's argument if it's not a string literal. And your macro will erroneously trigger an error for any const arrays. (Also note that there are no array literals, only constant arrays.)

Comment: well i hoped there is some ruse behind, last bullet is not so shifty more than obvious, use typeid(X).name() to check if it begins with "const char[" or "const char*". if so drop the assertion.